# Cannot obtain string data from another activity

Tags: java, android

i've got string data from secondary activity. then I'd like to change the title of marker on Main activity, yet it can't be read.
here is the data :

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 22 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        View view = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getView();
        addButton.setText(data.getStringExtra("Nama"));
        String nama = (data.getStringExtra("Nama"));


    }
```

the data can be read for `addButton`, but we can't get it for `String nama`

here is my Button :

```
addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
```

and here is my marker

```
private class RadiusCircle {

    private final Marker centerMarker;

    private final Circle circle;

    private double radius;

    public RadiusCircle(LatLng center, double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        centerMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(center)
                .title(nama)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bulet))
                .draggable(false));

        circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(center)
                .radius(radius)
                .strokeWidth(2)
                .strokeColor(mStrokeColor)
                .fillColor(mFillColor));
    }



    public void onStyleChange() {
        circle.setStrokeWidth(2);
        circle.setFillColor(mFillColor);
        circle.setStrokeColor(mStrokeColor);
    }
}
```

title `.title(nama)` is unobtainable, can i get some help? thanks for your kindness

Comment: You do realize that the `nama` variable is only available in that section and you don't have any access from out of that block?

Comment: yeah, so how can we access it from out of the block?

Comment: You must add a field in your activity and fill that.

Comment: @MohammadZ can you give me the example?

Comment: I think you've got your answer. If not, tell me to give you one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
String nama;
.....
..... 

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
if(requestCode == 22 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    View view = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getView();
    addButton.setText(data.getStringExtra("Nama"));
    nama = (data.getStringExtra("Nama"));

.....

}
```

Comment: thank you it help. but the `title.(nama)` still can't read the string. is there a way to make it readable?

Comment: If title is textview then you can write "title.setText(nama)"